# Summarizing polygon area using another polygon in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, spatial-statistics, area, overlay

I have a shapefile representing public/private lands in Montana.  This is a multipart shapefile where I've simplified attributes so that #1==private and #0==public.

Next I have a shapefile of counties for the state.  How could I easily summarize the total area of public vs private by county?

Do I need to rasterize and go about it that way?

I have an ArcEditor (Standard) and Spatial Analyst license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do a union of the two shapefiles.  Then select just the private lands from the union shapefile.  Summarize on CountyName, click the plus sign next to SHP_Area and choose "Sum".  This should give you a table that shows the total area of private lands per county.

Select just public lands and then summarize again to get the total area of public lands per county.

Getting percentages should be relatively straightforward if you join one of the summary tables to the other.